# How to send a message from XPC helper app to main application?

Tags: macos, cocoa, xpc, nsxpcconnection

I was successful in creating XPC service and communicating with XPC service by sending messages from main application. But what I want to know is, whether its possible to initiate a communication from XPC service to the main application. The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html) says XPC is bidirectional. It would be much appreciated if someone can point me in right direction with an example.

Please note,

- I want to launch the XPC from main application.
- communicate with XPC from main application.
- when some events occur, XPC should send a message to main application.

I succeeded in first two, but couldn't find any resource on the third one.

Thanks. :)

Comment: What have you tried in terms of calling back the main program?  Did you try using `exportedMethods` and `exportedObjects` from the main program?

Comment: Yes, I am experimenting with `remoteObjectInterface` from XPC service and `exportedObjects` from main application. I would be glad if you can provide an example.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and we will attempt to help you fix it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040765/communicate-with-another-app-using-xpc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040765/communicate-with-another-app-using-xpc

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Figured everything out. The following should be a decent example:

ProcessorListener.h (included in both client and server):

```
@protocol Processor

- (void) doProcessing: (void (^)(NSString *response))reply;

@end

@protocol Progress

- (void) updateProgress: (double) currentProgress;
- (void) finished;

@end

@interface ProcessorListener : NSObject<NSXPCListenerDelegate, Processor>

@property (weak) NSXPCConnection *xpcConnection;

@end
```

ProcessorListener.m: (Included in just the server)

```
#import "ProcessorListener.h"

@implementation ProcessorListener

- (BOOL)listener:(NSXPCListener *)listener shouldAcceptNewConnection:(NSXPCConnection *)newConnection
{
    [newConnection setExportedInterface: [NSXPCInterface interfaceWithProtocol:@protocol(Processor)]];
    [newConnection setExportedObject: self];
    self.xpcConnection = newConnection;

    newConnection.remoteObjectInterface = [NSXPCInterface interfaceWithProtocol: @protocol(Progress)];

    // connections start suspended by default, so resume and start receiving them
    [newConnection resume];

    return YES;
}

- (void) doProcessing: (void (^)(NSString *g))reply
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
      for(int index = 0; index < 60; ++index)
      {
         [NSThread sleepWithTimeInterval: 1];
         [[self.xpcConnection remoteObjectProxy] updateProgress: (double)index / (double)60 * 100];
      }

      [[self.xpcConnection remoteObjectProxy] finished];
    }

    // nil is a valid return value.
    reply(@"This is a reply!");
}

@end
```

MainApplication.m (your main app):

```
#import "ProcessorListener.h"

- (void) executeRemoteProcess
{
    // Create our connection
    NSXPCInterface * myCookieInterface = [NSXPCInterface interfaceWithProtocol: @protocol(Processor)];

    NSXPCConnection * connection = [[NSXPCConnection alloc] initWithServiceName: kServiceName];

    [connection setRemoteObjectInterface: myCookieInterface];

    connection.exportedInterface = [NSXPCInterface interfaceWithProtocol:@protocol(Progress)];
    connection.exportedObject = self;

    [connection resume];

    id<Processor> theProcessor = [connection remoteObjectProxyWithErrorHandler:^(NSError *err)
                       {
                           NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
                           [alert addButtonWithTitle: @"OK"];
                           [alert setMessageText: err.localizedDescription];
                           [alert setAlertStyle: NSWarningAlertStyle];

                           [alert performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(runModal) withObject: nil waitUntilDone: YES];
                       }];

    [theProcessor doProcessing: ^(NSString * response)
     {
        NSLog(@"Received response: %@", response);
     }];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Progress

- (void) updateProgress: (double) currentProgress
{
    NSLog(@"In progress: %f", currentProgress);
}

- (void) finished
{
    NSLog(@"Has finished!");
}

@end
```

Note that this code is is a condensed version based on my working code. It may not compile 100% but shows the key concepts used. In the example, the `doProcessing` runs async to show that the callbacks defined in the `Progress` protocol still get executed even after the initial method has return and the `Received response: This is a reply!` has been logged.

Comment: What if there are several connections to the processor? How do I know which connection called `doProcessing` so I could report progress to it?

Comment: @pointum you could pass another argument which identifies the process to `doProcessing`.

Comment: This is a great answer but why not talk about app and service instead of client and server when defining the different pieces and what goes where?

Comment: the secret sauce on this is that the 'the server' has to run in a certain context. by that i mean, if you run the server from gdb or command line this does not work.